# Newly generated coins

Tags: wallet, unconfirmed-transactions, hash, output

New to BTC world so my question is how and what can I do with newly generated coins what's the process and how to see balance of that in wallet? Can I send those to paper wallet

Comment: You can only generate coins by mining new blocks, but you can receive coins from anybody (via trade or donation). What do you mean by newly generated coins?

Answer (score 1):

> **New to BTC world**

Be very very careful about who you trust. Do your own independent research. Reading old questions on this website is a good start.

> **what can I do with newly generated coins**

People often ask this sort of question after downloading a mining game to their phone and "mining Bitcoin" on their phone. Unfortunately those are not real.

If you have real Bitcoin you already have a wallet, your wallet will show how many bitcoin you control.

Beware of watch-only addresses that let you see bitcoin amounts that you do not own and have no control over.

Beware of "testnet" bitcoins that are worthless.

Newly mined bitcoins are generally associated with a bitcoin-address that is controlled by the miner or mining pool. That address was derived from private keys which will be held in a wallet.

Mining bitcoin isn't something you can do casually.

Comment: Well the newly generated coins are in the blockchain.info they were donated to me from a friend and I'm trying to transfer those into my wallet and have been watching tutorials if the proper procedure.